# Xpath matches againt items

Tags: xpath-2.0

The matches function acts against a string (where the result is a single item of type string).  Looking for a way with XPath to do the same regular expression matches but against items (result is a sequence of nodes/items)?

Comment: If you are talking about the result of XPath 2.0 [`matches()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-matches) function evaluation, then you are wrong: evaluation result is an instance of `xs:boolean`.

Comment: @Alejandro I think he meant that you can do `matches( /foo/bar, 'regexp')` when the result of `/foo/bar` is a string. (Or to be more precise, a list with only one element.)

Comment: @biziclop: There are some restrictions on that: not singleton sequence can't be cast to xs:string and it would rise an error. A good XSLT processor might also rise an static error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//foo/bar[matches( ., 'regexp' )]
```

Is this what you're looking for or am I misunderstanding your question. This filters the `//foo/bar` nodelist based on the string value of every node. (The string value of elements is the concatenation of all the text nodes within it.)

Comment: Exactly....funny just tested the same thing but with matches(text(),'') but thanks for the help!!

Comment: @Matthew Young There is a slight difference with `text()` though: it returns a list of all the text nodes in that element. So if you have `<bar>text1<x/>text2</bar>` , `matches()` will complain.