# Does scrapy support regular expression in xpath?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

```
hoteldata = response.selector.xpath("//*[@id='js_itemlist']")
    for hoteldata in hoteldata:
        title = hoteldata.xpath("//*[@id='([jsheadline_]+\d{5}[0-9])']/span/text()").extract()
        partner_name = hoteldata.xpath("//*[@id='([js_item_]+\d{5}[0-9])']/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/strong[1]/text()").extract()
        price_single = hoteldata.xpath("//*[@id='([js_item_]+\d{5}[0-9])']/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/strong[2]/text()").extract()
        print title, partner_name, price_single
```

no error is coming nor output is coming

Comment: 2015-09-16 16:13:23 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-09-16 16:13:23 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 i
tems (at 0 items/min)

Comment: What is the relevance of that comment? If it is part of your question, please click the [edit] link underneath your question and simply add it to the question. See also [ask].

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> //*[@id='([jsheadline_]+\d{5}[0-9])']/span/text()
> ```

These, and the others in your post, are valid XPath, but do not use regular expressions, they merely test against **a string that looks like a regex**. If you want to know whether Scrapy supports it, [try to use the `matches()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147120/xpath-matches-againt-items), which is part of XPath 2.0. I do not know what engine Scrapy uses underneath, but you will receive an error if it fails.

Besides, your regex looks kinda odd. You use `[jsheadline_]+`, which is a one-or-more repeated character class, but it looks as if you want to test for the string `"jsheadline_"`. If that's the case, you can use the `contains()` function and the `substring-before()` and `substring-after()` functions to test for the presence of that string followed by some digits. These functions work with any version of XPath, just google them and you'll find plenty of examples.